# BindingAdapter with drawable parameter not accepting drawable parameter

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-jetpack

BindingAdapter code:

```
    @BindingAdapter(value = ["vertical_divider_decorator_drawable"], requireAll = false)
    @JvmStatic
    fun bindRecyclerViewDivider(recyclerView: RecyclerView, vertical_divider_decorator_drawable: Drawable) {
        val decorator = DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL)
        decorator.setDrawable(vertical_divider_decorator_drawable)
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decorator)
    }

    @BindingAdapter(value = ["vertical_divider_decorator_drawable"], requireAll = false)
    @JvmStatic
    fun bindRecyclerViewDivider(recyclerView: RecyclerView, vertical_divider_decorator_drawable: Int ) {
        val decorator = DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL)
        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(recyclerView.context.resources, vertical_divider_decorator_drawable, null)
            ?.let { drawable -> decorator.setDrawable(drawable) }
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decorator)
    }
```

RecyclerView in XML:

```
     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:vertical_divider_decorator_drawable="@drawable/row_divider"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        />
```

Build error:

```
AAPT: error: attribute vertical_divider_decorator_drawable (aka com.package:vertical_divider_decorator_drawable) not found.
```

BindingAdapter has both Drawable and Int parameters but still the compiler not accepting both drawbales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change from:
`app:vertical_divider_decorator_drawable="@drawable/row_divider"`
to:
`app:vertical_divider_decorator_drawable="@{@drawable/row_divider}"`

If not helped, try this:
`fun bindRecyclerViewDivider(recyclerView: RecyclerView, vertical_divider_decorator_drawable: Int) {`

Comment: app:vertical_divider_decorator_drawable="@{@drawable/row_divider}" This worked. thank you